# Lack of research opportunities in Israel

Tags: phd, international-students, israel

I am currently researching where I would like to do my PhD. I have always been drawn to Israel (this has nothing to do with religion or politics or anything similar but rather with warm weather and hummus) so I also included it in a list of potential destinations. However, I am very surprised that I virtually never come across

- advertisements for PhD positions in Israel
- Israeli institutes being involved in research projects or international programs
- someone who has studied/worked at an Israeli university
  ...

Also, a few years ago, I contacted multiple Israeli universities about the possibility of conducting my thesis there and got very limited response.

When I compare this to countries with somewhat similar "level of development", such as Canada, Austria, Belgium, Germany, Italy, etc., it feels completely different. From all these countries I get a feeling that they expect and encourage foreign students/researchers to come and that they work to attract them (both at a national level and at a level of individual universities)

**Question:** Are there any reasons for Israel seemingly not being (a) involved much in international research collaborations and (b) interested in foreign students/researchers?

My field is geoinformatics and remote sensing.

Comment: I think you are mistaken entirely. Israel is small, so the output may be less than more populous places. But there are excellent universities there.

Comment: Does Israel advertise PhD positions? US universities don't really, so I wouldn't take that as discouragement

Comment: I think that the Technion should have English programmes and in my experience (in Mathematics) even if a course is officially announced in Hebrew it might be in English if there is demand for it. Googling a bit I found the following page: https://cee.technion.ac.il/research-graduate-studies/research-and-graduate-studies/mapping-and-geo-information/

Comment: As far as I understood, in Israel they do not necessarily advertise PhD places. You should look up the groups that do geoinformatics and contact the PI about opportunities. E.g. the Hebrew Universities geoinformatics group https://neev.huji.ac.il/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Are there any reasons for Israel seemingly not being (a) involved much in international research collaborations and (b) interested in foreign students/researchers?

Your assumption (a) is completely incorrect — it’s hard for me to think of a statement that’s further than the truth.

Assumption (b) is correct in the context of foreign *students*, and this has a simple explanation. It’s mostly a language issue: PhD programs in Israel are offered in Hebrew, and it’s extremely rare for foreign students looking for a place to do their PhD to be willing to invest several years to learn the language at the level they’d need to know it to be successful in doing a PhD. The ones who would entertain that possibility are small enough in numbers, and highly motivated enough, that there’s no need for graduate programs to do special outreach targeted at them. Any postings for PhD programs or positions will be in Hebrew, and if you are not a Hebrew speaker you will not be able to find and read them.

There are a few exceptions to this. The Weizmann Institute of Science has English as its official language and does attract a reasonable number of foreign students. Tel Aviv University has an English speaking medical school program and, I vaguely recall, a business master’s program. There might be other isolated programs for which the language barrier wouldn’t be an issue.

Comment: I see. I didn't think of this because in Europe its quite the standard that PhD programs are in English. And because Israeli people always speak perfect English so I thought surely their universities will be in English, too.

Comment: @JanPisl you might want to revisit your assumptions about Europe as well...

Comment: Indeed, the idea that "everyone does everything in English" is slightly strange to me (a native Amer English speaker). This was certainly not the case just a few decades ago, to begin with, and it is not at all reliably so today, in many fields. The sort of "scientific language colonialism" that pretends that "everyone writes in English now" is really not a useful/safe/warranted pretense.

Comment: All I can say is that the past few months, I have been researching PhD opportunities across Europe, including Germany, Austria, Switzerland, Finland, Sweden, Norway, Spain, UK, France, Belgium, Denmark and the Netherlands. I research people that do what I want to do and then look up their institution and contact them. From the countries above, only in France I had a problem with (only) speaking English. Of course, I only contacted a small fraction of all universities and more likely those that do use English.

Comment: I don't understand why you talk about "scientific language colonialism" when, in my opinion, its just a matter of using a language that allows people from different countries to collaborate easily and, more generally, to interact with each other. And why would you say it's "not useful". In my experience of studying and doing research in Europe, it was exactly that - useful. I respect your opinion and I am sure you have good reasons to have it. But I don't get where it comes from

Comment: @JanPisl It is amazing that English should remain *lingua franca*  (pun intended) in the EU when, once the UK has left, no EU country will have English as its designated language (the Irish has designated Gaelic as their language).  See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impact_of_Brexit_on_the_European_Union#Languages

Comment: @JanPisl well, you do have a point that Israel has a different attitude than the typical Western European country about the issue of foreign students. There are many reasons for this, and I didn’t mean to suggest Israel and those other countries are completely similar on this matter. Basically, if you visit Israel you will discover it’s quite a unique place with a lot of surprising aspects to it that aren’t quite like anywhere else you know, which is why these sorts of extrapolations you’re making don’t always apply. Anyway, good luck, I hope you find the opportunities you’re looking for.

Comment: @JanPisl This is presumably subject and location dependent, but in my experience you'd be in for a rude shock if you expect to do a ph.D. program in France without speaking French (in Germany it's different, although I would still recommend to learn German).

Comment: I feel I should mention [Technion](https://www.technion.ac.il/en/home-2/) as another notable example of an English-speaking Israeli university. Although I haven't done due research to fully reconfirm that, but I do vividly remember that we used some of their study materials when I was in college and they were written fully in English.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero English wasn't chosen as the de facto shared language due to the UK.

Comment: @undercatapplaudsMonica the Technion is not an “English speaking university”.

Comment: @DanRomik I've double checked and you are correct, although the university does position itself as an English-friendly university. Quoting [this page](https://graduate.technion.ac.il/en/prospective-students/language_of_studies), "By default, classes at the Technion are conducted in Hebrew. Therefore basic knowledge of Hebrew is recommended. However, *all Technion departments have committed to teaching graduate courses in English, under some conditions, following a request by an international student per a specific course*."

Comment: I am doing my PhD at the Hebrew University in Jerusalem in English. As far as I heard, they actually do want to encourage researchers to come. I am not sure of geoinformatics, though...

Answer (score 3):

Israel has about the same population as Austria, and in my experience the research opportunities in both countries are about equal.  They both have high levels of international engagement for their size.

The other countries have more population that Israel.  Some of them have a lot more.  Those countries have more opportunities, if you do not adjust for population.

Comment: thanks. i have taken into account population. specifically in Austria, I have found a number of opportunities, such as PhD calls, international programs in which Austrian universities participated, PhD programs that combined research with industry placements, etc. Similar in Finland that has less people and Belgium that has a little bit more. None of this in Israel. But perhaps it's a question of language as the other answer suggested or I just didn't look in the right places

Comment: Or perhaps it is specific to your discipline.  The Israeli government has unique funding priorities.

Comment: yes definitely that can be the case. that's why i mentioned my discipline in the question. "The Israeli government has unique funding priorities" could be exactly the explanation

Answer (score 1):

The assumption that Israeli universities have few international research cooperations contradicts my experience with Israeli universities. I also have the impression that the number of international students is not particularly low compared to European universities (again just anecdotal evidence).

In addition to the points mentioned in other answers, I think that one reason for few announcements of positions could be that (at least) some Israeli universities typically fund the PhD students (and even the PostDocs) via scholarships.

As an engineering related example, you can find a lot of information on the website of the Technion's gradute school: https://graduate.technion.ac.il/en/prospective-students/graduate_degree_studies_at_technion

It also looks like in practice many of these programmes are actually taught in English and in my experience most people in Israel have a rather good level of English.